# Hiding a folder in Android

Tags: android

I want to make an application in android ,which can hide my selected files are folders from Sdcard . your suggestion will be appreciated.Thanks!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135179/how-to-hide-a-folder-in-sdcard-in-android

Answer (score 2):

In the Android file system (which is `UNIX` based), you can prepend a file or folder name with a period, and it will be invisible to standard file browsers (though not un-findable). So for example, the file `.hidden` will be hidden, whereas `visible` would be seen by users.

Comment: This is partially true. Prepending name with dot is NOT handled on filesystem level. Files/folders with name prepended with dot are just regular files/folders. The fact they are sometimes treated as "hidden" is handled on application level (i.e. `ls` or `mc` eetc). So UNIX or not makes absolutely no difference - app need to support this naming schema as there no magic

Comment: It is good to further clarify this, however I did specify this by using the phrase "invisible to *standard* file browsers."