# How to hide folder in sdcard programmatically in android

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

I have an app with xyz.zip folder which is extracting after installation in sdcard. Folder contains a lot of files(e.g Video,audio,etc.).During installing app I wanna hide that folder and hide all items of folder.
Thanks in advance.

Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: You should at least include what you've tried to do to achieve it. Googling it before asking is a good practice too.

Answer (score 5):

Use a function like this:

```
public static void hideFile(File file){
    File dstFile = new File(file.getParent(), "." + file.getName());
    file.renameTo(dstFile);
}
```

Please note I did not try the code, but it should at least give you the idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide folder in Android or any Linux based system just add . as prefix to folder or file name.

Answer stolen from here: [How to hide a folder in sdcard in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135179/how-to-hide-a-folder-in-sdcard-in-android?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for replying ....Can u elaborate programmatically  how can i achieve this thing.

Comment: Use the code which @FD_ wrote. Be sure to add the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE