# Android: Storage option method for users able to import files

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm making an app where the user can choose a specific directory (or open in another app) and select files to import so the app can read it. Which storage option will be the best suited?

Shared Prefences, Internal Storage or External Storage?
If you're wondering what I'm storing, it is a bunch of google map markers, all the information written into the file.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **If it is a file best can be a file in a hidden folder in internal Storage.**

**Why hidden folder ?**

The content in the file is **bunch of google map markers**. So this file you must be using somewhere to read from that and use that marker data as per your needs in application.

If it is in some hidden folder user cannot find it and so that cannot delete it's contents (in normal cases excluding the case when user has enabled the option of `Show hidden files & folders`) & your application data is safe at some extent.

**Why internal storage ?**

As it is a none removable storage it can be more reliable not 100% but at least 80%. If you will do it in external storage and the `SdCard` gets removed then you might face **FileNotFound** or something similar to that.

Thing you may need : [How to hide a folder in sdcard in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135179/how-to-hide-a-folder-in-sdcard-in-android?rq=1)

Comment: does this mean people can import their own files and open them?

Comment: but if its private then how does it work? any code examples?

Comment: private ?? you are talking about the file with markers ?? how can a file be private ??

Comment: @J.Tey please mark the answer as correct if it is helpful..!!

Comment: but if it's 'hidden' then how does the user import their own files?

Comment: I suggest you not let user import their files instead you can put them in `raw` folder and after installing the app copy them into internal storage. Reason: **The user imported files may not have the format you decided for marker values**